# Open pdf in aspx page with content place holder

Tags: asp.net, pdf.js

I am using pdfjs to display a pdf file in aspx page. I am using a page which is inherited by a master page. The problem is when I am clicking on any option of pdf like search,zoom etc the page is getting reloaded just because of contentplaceholder.

If I call this inside a plane page(without masterpage) It is working fine.

Test page code:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/masterpages/testing.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="displaypdf.aspx.cs" Inherits="displaypdf" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">



         <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
     <div class="container">  
        <div class="form-box" style="margin:65px 0 40px 0" id="availab" runat="server">
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 login">
    <div class="thumbnail-preview">

        <div id="outerContainer">

          <div id="sidebarContainer">
            <div id="toolbarSidebar">
              <div class="splitToolbarButton toggled">
                <button id="viewThumbnail" class="toolbarButton group toggled" title="Show Thumbnails" tabindex="2" data-l10n-id="thumbs">
                   <span data-l10n-id="thumbs_label">Thumbnails</span>
                </button>
                <button id="viewOutline" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Document Outline" tabindex="3" data-l10n-id="outline">
                   <span data-l10n-id="outline_label">Document Outline</span>
                </button>
                <button id="viewAttachments" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Attachments" tabindex="4" data-l10n-id="attachments">
                   <span data-l10n-id="attachments_label">Attachments</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebarContent">
              <div id="thumbnailView">
              </div>
              <div id="outlineView" class="hidden">
              </div>
              <div id="attachmentsView" class="hidden">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  <!-- sidebarContainer -->

          <div id="mainContainer">
            <div class="findbar hidden doorHanger hiddenSmallView" id="findbar">
              <label for="findInput" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_label">Find:</label>
              <input id="findInput" class="toolbarField" tabindex="91">
              <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                <button class="toolbarButton findPrevious" title="" id="findPrevious" tabindex="92" data-l10n-id="find_previous">
                  <span data-l10n-id="find_previous_label">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                <button class="toolbarButton findNext" title="" id="findNext" tabindex="93" data-l10n-id="find_next">
                  <span data-l10n-id="find_next_label">Next</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <input type="checkbox" id="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarField">
              <label for="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarLabel" tabindex="94" data-l10n-id="find_highlight">Highlight all</label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="findMatchCase" class="toolbarField">
              <label for="findMatchCase" class="toolbarLabel" tabindex="95" data-l10n-id="find_match_case_label">Match case</label>
              <span id="findMsg" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
            </div>  <!-- findbar -->

            <div id="secondaryToolbar" class="secondaryToolbar hidden doorHangerRight">
              <div id="secondaryToolbarButtonContainer">
                <button id="secondaryPresentationMode" class="secondaryToolbarButton presentationMode visibleLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="51" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
                  <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
                </button>

                <button id="secondaryOpenFile" class="secondaryToolbarButton openFile visibleLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="52" data-l10n-id="open_file">
                  <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
                </button>

                <button id="secondaryPrint" class="secondaryToolbarButton print visibleMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="53" data-l10n-id="print">
                  <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
                </button>

                <button id="secondaryDownload" class="secondaryToolbarButton download visibleMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="54" data-l10n-id="download">
                  <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
                </button>

                <a href="#" id="secondaryViewBookmark" class="secondaryToolbarButton bookmark visibleSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="55" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
                  <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
                </a>

                <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator visibleLargeView"></div>

                <button id="firstPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton firstPage" title="Go to First Page" tabindex="56" data-l10n-id="first_page">
                  <span data-l10n-id="first_page_label">Go to First Page</span>
                </button>
                <button id="lastPage" class="secondaryToolbarButton lastPage" title="Go to Last Page" tabindex="57" data-l10n-id="last_page">
                  <span data-l10n-id="last_page_label">Go to Last Page</span>
                </button>

                <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

                <button id="pageRotateCw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCw" title="Rotate Clockwise" tabindex="58" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw">
                  <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw_label">Rotate Clockwise</span>
                </button>
                <button id="pageRotateCcw" class="secondaryToolbarButton rotateCcw" title="Rotate Counterclockwise" tabindex="59" data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw">
                  <span data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw_label">Rotate Counterclockwise</span>
                </button>

                <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

                <button id="toggleHandTool" class="secondaryToolbarButton handTool" title="Enable hand tool" tabindex="60" data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable">
                  <span data-l10n-id="hand_tool_enable_label">Enable hand tool</span>
                </button>

                <div class="horizontalToolbarSeparator"></div>

                <button id="documentProperties" class="secondaryToolbarButton documentProperties" title="Document Properties…" tabindex="61" data-l10n-id="document_properties">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_label">Document Properties…</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>  <!-- secondaryToolbar -->

            <div class="toolbar">
              <div id="toolbarContainer">
                <div id="toolbarViewer">
                  <div id="toolbarViewerLeft">
                    <button id="sidebarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Toggle Sidebar" tabindex="11" data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar">
                      <span data-l10n-id="toggle_sidebar_label">Toggle Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div>
                    <button id="viewFind" class="toolbarButton group hiddenSmallView" title="Find in Document" tabindex="12" data-l10n-id="findbar">
                       <span data-l10n-id="findbar_label">Find</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                      <button class="toolbarButton pageUp" title="Previous Page" id="previous" tabindex="13" data-l10n-id="previous">
                        <span data-l10n-id="previous_label">Previous</span>
                      </button>
                      <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                      <button class="toolbarButton pageDown" title="Next Page" id="next" tabindex="14" data-l10n-id="next">
                        <span data-l10n-id="next_label">Next</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <label id="pageNumberLabel" class="toolbarLabel" for="pageNumber" data-l10n-id="page_label">Page: </label>
                    <input type="number" id="pageNumber" class="toolbarField pageNumber" value="1" size="4" min="1" tabindex="15">
                    <span id="numPages" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
                    <button id="presentationMode" class="toolbarButton presentationMode hiddenLargeView" title="Switch to Presentation Mode" tabindex="31" data-l10n-id="presentation_mode">
                      <span data-l10n-id="presentation_mode_label">Presentation Mode</span>
                    </button>

                    <button id="openFile" class="toolbarButton openFile hiddenLargeView" title="Open File" tabindex="32" data-l10n-id="open_file">
                      <span data-l10n-id="open_file_label">Open</span>
                    </button>

                    <button id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" title="Print" tabindex="33" data-l10n-id="print">
                      <span data-l10n-id="print_label">Print</span>
                    </button>

                    <button id="download" class="toolbarButton download hiddenMediumView" title="Download" tabindex="34" data-l10n-id="download">
                      <span data-l10n-id="download_label">Download</span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- <div class="toolbarButtonSpacer"></div> -->
                    <a href="#" id="viewBookmark" class="toolbarButton bookmark hiddenSmallView" title="Current view (copy or open in new window)" tabindex="35" data-l10n-id="bookmark">
                      <span data-l10n-id="bookmark_label">Current View</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="verticalToolbarSeparator hiddenSmallView"></div>

                    <button id="secondaryToolbarToggle" class="toolbarButton" title="Tools" tabindex="36" data-l10n-id="tools">
                      <span data-l10n-id="tools_label">Tools</span>
                    </button> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="outerCenter">
                    <div class="innerCenter" id="toolbarViewerMiddle">
                      <div class="splitToolbarButton">
                        <button id="zoomOut" class="toolbarButton zoomOut" title="Zoom Out" tabindex="21" data-l10n-id="zoom_out">
                          <span data-l10n-id="zoom_out_label">Zoom Out</span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="splitToolbarButtonSeparator"></div>
                        <button id="zoomIn" class="toolbarButton zoomIn" title="Zoom In" tabindex="22" data-l10n-id="zoom_in">
                          <span data-l10n-id="zoom_in_label">Zoom In</span>
                         </button>
                      </div>
                      <span id="scaleSelectContainer" class="dropdownToolbarButton">
                         <select id="scaleSelect" title="Zoom" tabindex="23" data-l10n-id="zoom">
                          <option id="pageAutoOption" title="" value="auto" selected="selected" data-l10n-id="page_scale_auto">Automatic Zoom</option>
                          <option id="pageActualOption" title="" value="page-actual" data-l10n-id="page_scale_actual">Actual Size</option>
                          <option id="pageFitOption" title="" value="page-fit" data-l10n-id="page_scale_fit">Fit Page</option>
                          <option id="pageWidthOption" title="" value="page-width" data-l10n-id="page_scale_width">Full Width</option>
                          <option id="customScaleOption" title="" value="custom"></option>
                          <option title="" value="0.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 50 }'>50%</option>
                          <option title="" value="0.75" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 75 }'>75%</option>
                          <option title="" value="1" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 100 }'>100%</option>
                          <option title="" value="1.25" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 125 }'>125%</option>
                          <option title="" value="1.5" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 150 }'>150%</option>
                          <option title="" value="2" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 200 }'>200%</option>
                          <option title="" value="3" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 300 }'>300%</option>
                          <option title="" value="4" data-l10n-id="page_scale_percent" data-l10n-args='{ "scale": 400 }'>400%</option>
                        </select>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="loadingBar">
                  <div class="progress">
                    <div class="glimmer">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <menu type="context" id="viewerContextMenu">
              <menuitem id="contextFirstPage" label="First Page"
                        data-l10n-id="first_page"></menuitem>
              <menuitem id="contextLastPage" label="Last Page"
                        data-l10n-id="last_page"></menuitem>
              <menuitem id="contextPageRotateCw" label="Rotate Clockwise"
                        data-l10n-id="page_rotate_cw"></menuitem>
              <menuitem id="contextPageRotateCcw" label="Rotate Counter-Clockwise"
                        data-l10n-id="page_rotate_ccw"></menuitem>
            </menu>

            <div id="viewerContainer" tabindex="0">
              <div id="viewer" class="pdfViewer"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="errorWrapper" hidden='true'>
              <div id="errorMessageLeft">
                <span id="errorMessage"></span>
                <button id="errorShowMore" data-l10n-id="error_more_info">
                  More Information
                </button>
                <button id="errorShowLess" data-l10n-id="error_less_info" hidden='true'>
                  Less Information
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="errorMessageRight">
                <button id="errorClose" data-l10n-id="error_close">
                  Close
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="clearBoth"></div>
              <textarea id="errorMoreInfo" hidden='true' readonly="readonly"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- mainContainer -->

          <div id="overlayContainer" class="hidden">
            <div id="passwordOverlay" class="container hidden">
              <div class="dialog">
                <div class="row">
                  <p id="passwordText" data-l10n-id="password_label">Enter the password to open this PDF file:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <input type="password" id="password" class="toolbarField" />
                </div>
                <div class="buttonRow">
                  <button id="passwordCancel" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_cancel">Cancel</span></button>
                  <button id="passwordSubmit" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="password_ok">OK</span></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="documentPropertiesOverlay" class="container hidden">
              <div class="dialog">
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_name">File name:</span> <p id="fileNameField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_file_size">File size:</span> <p id="fileSizeField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_title">Title:</span> <p id="titleField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_author">Author:</span> <p id="authorField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_subject">Subject:</span> <p id="subjectField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_keywords">Keywords:</span> <p id="keywordsField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creation_date">Creation Date:</span> <p id="creationDateField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_modification_date">Modification Date:</span> <p id="modificationDateField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_creator">Creator:</span> <p id="creatorField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="separator"></div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_producer">PDF Producer:</span> <p id="producerField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_version">PDF Version:</span> <p id="versionField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span data-l10n-id="document_properties_page_count">Page Count:</span> <p id="pageCountField">-</p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttonRow">
                  <button id="documentPropertiesClose" class="overlayButton"><span data-l10n-id="document_properties_close">Close</span></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  <!-- overlayContainer -->

        </div>
         <div id="printContainer"></div>
    <div id="mozPrintCallback-shim" hidden>
      <style scoped>
    #mozPrintCallback-shim {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999999;

      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
    #mozPrintCallback-shim[hidden] {
      display: none;
    }
    @media print {
      #mozPrintCallback-shim {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    #mozPrintCallback-shim .mozPrintCallback-dialog-box {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: -50px auto 0;
      position: relative;
      top: 45%;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 220px;
      max-width: 400px;

      padding: 9px;

      border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5);
      border-radius: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

      background-color: #474747;

      color: hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
    #mozPrintCallback-shim .progress-row {
      clear: both;
      padding: 1em 0;
    }
    #mozPrintCallback-shim progress {
      width: 100%;
    }
    #mozPrintCallback-shim .relative-progress {
      clear: both;
      float: right;
    }
    #mozPrintCallback-shim .progress-actions {
      clear: both;
    }
      </style>
      <div class="mozPrintCallback-dialog-box">
        <!-- TODO: Localise the following strings -->
        Preparing document for printing...
        <div class="progress-row">
          <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
          <span class="relative-progress">0%</span>
        </div>
        <div class="progress-actions">
          <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="mozPrintCallback-cancel">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
    <div class="upload-form-main">
    <div class="upload-form-left">


    </div>
    <div class="upload-form-right">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title*">
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="crsenumber" placeholder="Course Number*">
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input id="college" class="form-control form-control-new2 form-control-new3" placeholder="College*" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control form-control-new2" id="uploadtype">
            <asp:Literal ID="lituploadtype" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <input id="discipline" autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-new2 form-control-new3" type="text" placeholder="Disciplene*" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control form-control-new2" id="price">
      <option>Price</option>
      <option>Price 1</option>
      <option>Price 2</option>
      <option>Price 3</option>
      <option>Price 4</option>
      <option>Price 5</option>
    </select>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proffessor" placeholder="Prof.">
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="upload-textarea"><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Description*" id ="desc"></textarea></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="upload-tags">
        <div id="tagscontainer" class="tags-in"></div><textarea id="tags" class="form-control" placeholder="Tags" rows="2"></textarea></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
          <label class="radio"><input name="RadioGroup1" type="radio" value="Private"  /><span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span> Private &nbsp;</label>
          <label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Public" checked="checked" /><span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span> Public</label>
          <br />
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-default" onclick ="submitupload();return false;">Done</button></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

        </div>
       <style>

       </style> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Code behind src:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Literal1.Text = "<script>var DEFAULT_URL = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf';</script>";
    }
```

Master page code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testing.master.cs" Inherits="masterpages_testing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/css/viewer.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/locale/locale.properties"/>
<script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/pdfjs/l10n.js"></script>
<script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/pdfjs/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/pdfjs/debugger.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/pdfjs/viewer.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"]%>/js/upload2.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share all the relevant code

Comment: I have posted the code please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake:

```
<button id="viewAttachments" class="toolbarButton group" title="Show Attachments" tabindex="4" data-l10n-id="attachments">
                   <span data-l10n-id="attachments_label">Attachments</span>
                </button>
```

The button inside the form will act as a submit button so need to modify only `type="button"`. This has resolved my issue.